How do I select faces vertices or faces that are visible in the 3d viewport and unobstructed by other faces of any mesh in the 3d viewport
Title kind of says it all: how do I select faces vertices or faces that are visible in the 3d viewport and unobstructed by other faces of any mesh in the 3d viewport
I am trying to get the viewport camera location like so:
def get_3d_view_camera():
    area = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D"][0]
    region = [region for region in area.regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0]

    r3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d
    view_mat = r3d.view_matrix

    loc, rot, sca = view_mat.decompose()

    return loc

and then to get all the faces that get hit like so:
def visible_faces(bm, if True or face.select):
    indices = [(index, face.calc_center_median_weighted()) for index, face in enumerate(bm.faces) ]

    outside_faces = []
    for index, center in indices:
        direction = (center - camera_origin).normalized()
        # Cast a ray from the camera position to the face center
        result, location, normal, face_index, obj, matrix = bpy.context.scene.ray_cast(bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph, camera_origin, direction)
        
        # If the ray hits the same face, it's visible, so we keep it
        if face_index == index:
            outside_faces.append(index)
    return outside_faces
``

